# IoC: Dependency Injection with a static IoC container

Tags: dependency-injection, static, inversion-of-control

Is it a good idea to put e.g. autofac/ninject in a static class that I can access is from different assemblies/projects?

static class MyContainer
{
 static IoCContainer ContainerOfCurrentRuntimeContext;
}

If I use this, I can use the same IoC-context in different projects.

Comment: But if you do this it would mean that other parts of your code will call it to fetch instances, which is the exact contrary to what inversion of control means. Classes should not be responsible for fetching their dependencies. Those dependencies should be passed either as constructor parameters (constructor injection) or properties (property injection). Your DI container should be visible only in a single place of your application which is normally the outermost shell.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: No, it is not the opposite of inversion of control. Inversion of control just says we should talk to an abstraction, and should not create objects ourselves. It is however, the opposite of Dependency Injection.

Comment: Please search Stackoverflow and Google for "Service locator anti-pattern". Using a container that is globally accessible is called the "Service Locator pattern" and it is considered to be an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this approach will add two new problem: *singleton* and *service locator* patterns (both counted as anti-patterns). As result your code will be coupled to new dependency: *your DI contaner*.

Usually you could overcome limitations of using *service locator*, but this will not worth doing, as it's much simple to introduce *composition root* for DI.

By the way, you could have one configuration and use it in all your different projects.

Comment: Okay thank you. The point with the single-configuration: But in that case I wouldn't get the same instances, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, _one_ Dependency Injection _kernel_ (in terms of nIninject) could resolve same dependency object multiple times. This is done by declaring specific _scope_ (in terms of nIninject). You could specify that DI will inject literally the same instance of dependency every time it has been requested in scope of thread or http request. And you could also define your own scope.